# Center element of carousel

Tags: html, css

I'm making a carousel of images for a store. I'm using `scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;` on the container and `scroll-snap-align: center;` for the images on it. The problem is that the container is wider than some of the images, the images are uploaded by the user and sometimes are wide, sometimes are tall...

So, if the image is tall the height is set to 100% and the width is set to auto so it doesn't get deformed. But that makes the element show on the carousel... and a little bit of the next image shows up.

I'd like to make each image wide enough so that the carousel only shows one image at the time.

I thought using `margin` like this:

```
img {
  margin: 0 calc((100% - 'width of the image') /2);
}
```

That would make each image to have margin on both sides, show centered and make it the only element visible on the carousel.

Is there any way I can get that 'width of the image'? Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `div`s with `width: 100%` in the carousel such that there is exactly one element visible at all times.
And then you put the `img`s into the `div`s and horizontally center them (e.g. using `margin: 0 auto`).
All of the elements should have `height: 100%`

Comment: Such a simple yet elegant solution... how did I not think about this? I obsessed trying to find out the 'width of the image' that I didn't even think another approach. Thanks!